# Typescript `Object is possibly undefined` error in code unreachable by an `undefined` value

Tags: typescript

How do I correctly resolve the following Typescript error—`Object is possibly 'undefined'.`—in an area of code that is unreachable by an `undefined` value. It is protected by a type guard executed in an external function.

```
type MaybeString = string | undefined;

let a: MaybeString = 'hello';
let b: MaybeString;

function getLength(string: MaybeString) {
  if (!isString(string)) {
    return -1;
  }
  return string.length;
}

function isString(string: MaybeString) {
  return typeof string === 'string';
}
```

[image: Highlighted error]
[image: Text error]

Comment: `return string?.length` (you also shouldn't use `string` as a variable name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change isString's return type to:

```
function isString(str: MaybeString): str is string {
   return typeof str === 'string';
}
```

For more information, see their documentation on user-defined type guards: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards